# should verify that the value age the user enters is considered valid, lying in the range between 0 and 150.and it should use the.matches(<...>) method

Tags: java

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
public class validAge
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = scan.nextLine();
        age(s);

    }
    public static void age(String s)
    {

        if(s.matches("[0-150]{1,3}"))
        {
            System.out.println("Age is valid");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Age is NOT valid");
        }
    }
}
```

i cant make it to print not valid age when the user inputs 150+ and same print statement when ages entered is negative. All of this has to be done using the .matches(<..>) method.
this is what i have done.

Comment: Why is regex a requirement?  Is this a regex learning exercise?

Answer (score 2):

That regex isn't correct.

It's complicated by the fact that your requirement says up to 150.

Break your problem into pieces:

1. Do a null check.  If the String is empty or null you should say it's invalid
2. The first 99 years are easy: `s.matches("[0-9]{1,2}")`
3. The problem is checking 100-150.  You can't do what you posted.  How can you check using regular expressions?  First digit must be 1; second digit must be 0-5; third digit must be 0-9.

Maybe a pattern like this for the third digit.  It needs to be optional, since you won't have one for 0-99.

```
"1[0-5][0-9]"
```

Comment: I think third pattern will check range between 100-159

Comment: Probably not right.  No time to check in all detail.  Answer is intended to lead the OP to think about it differently.  Looked at yours: agreed, it's better.

Comment: And you have explained very nicely indeed

Answer (score 1):

Your regex doesn't look quite right [0-150] will check anything between 0 and 1 and 50 literally.

```
^(150|1[0-4][0-9]|[0-9]{1,2})$
```

Try using this regex. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This short script tests an array of strings.  Both the commented out line and if condition work equally well.  In your question, [0-150]{1,3} would match one-to-three digit strings containing only 0,1 and 5. So, 0,1,5,10,11,15,...105,115,150.

(\d{1,2})|(1[0-4]\d)|150 covers your range as a set of groups.
\d{1,2} - gives you any one digit string or two digit string.
1[0-4]\d - gives you a three digit string starting with 1, then second digit 0-4 and finally any digit.
150 - matches 150.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, IOException
{
    String b[] =
    { "0", "1", "2", "3", "150", "80", "90", "45", "100", "120", "200",
            "-3", "-4", "151", "-1" };
    for (int ai = 0; ai < b.length; ai++)
    {
        // if(b[ai].matches("([0-9]?[0-9])|(1[0-4][0-9])|150"))
        if (b[ai].matches("(\\d{1,2})|(1[0-4]\\d)|150"))
        {
            System.out.println("Age is valid " + b[ai]);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Age is NOT valid" + b[ai]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i have another programe

Comment: it is meant print out not valid if it does nt match the if statement but when i run it the else statement along with the if statemnets gets printed out at the same time idont knw y its happening @ProgrammersBlock

Answer (score 0):

Your welcome:

```
if(s.matches("^([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-4][0-9]|150)$"))
```